# Decal shrinkwrap black background

Tags: shrinkwrap

I don't know how to make the background of my image transparent. The file is a PNG with a transparent background and the image material is already in alpha mode. I want to render in Cycles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you mixing your shader with?

Comment: Sorry, it was useless, I removed it.

Comment: Please pack your image before sharing (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: You are using a shrinkwrap modifier with a non-zero offset:  this is causing a shadow.  I downloaded your file that doesn't pack the image, but used my own PNG image with alpha channel. But I'm thinking how to get rid of the bleed-throught I see.

Comment: I think you just have to disable "shadows" or "cast shadows" or whatever it's called on the object as a setting in eevee

Comment: I refreshed the link to download the file with the file packed

Comment: @james_t and Gorgious were right: I removed the shadows from cycles settings. But the background of the image (although now softer) is still visible. I refresh the download link so you can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase light bounces to something more reasonable than 1. Transparent bounces are the issue here.

[image]